# getting greatest value in specific column and row

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is going to have several time stamp entries added throughout the day with a specific employee ID tied to each entry. I am curious how I would get the first timestamp of the day and the last time stamp of the day to calculate amount of time worked for that specific employee on the specific date. My table is below:

```
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| id | employeeID | date     | timeIn  | jobDescription      | equipType | unitNumber | unitHours | timeOut |
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
|  1 |          1 | 01/13/13 | 8:17 pm | Worked in Hubbard   | Dozer     | 2D         |     11931 | 8:17 pm |
|  2 |          1 | 01/13/13 | 8:17 pm | Worked in Jefferson | Excavator | 01E        |      8341 | 8:18 pm |
+----+------------+----------+---------+---------------------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

so far I have a query like this to retrieve the time values:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `timeRecords` WHERE `date`= :dateToday AND `employeeID` = :employeeID ORDER BY employeeID ASC');
    $stmt->execute(array(':employeeID' => $_SESSION['employeeID'], ':dateToday' => $dateToday));
```

But I am unsure of how to obtain the greatest value in the `timeOut` column

Comment: So you want the least `timeIn` and the greatest `timeOut`? (that won't give you the total time worked if the individual has clocked in and out several times)

Comment: your correct, I have thought about the problem I may have with that I will need to implement a solution that checks if there was a gap in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, you just need the aggregate `MAX()` and `MIN()` grouped by `employeeID`.  Use the [`TIMEDIFF()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) to calculate the difference in time between the two.

```
SELECT 
  `employeeID`,
  MIN(`timeIn`) AS `timeIn`,
  MAX(`timeOut`) AS `timeOut`,
  TIMEDIFF(MAX(`timeOut`), MIN(`timeIn`)) AS `totalTime`
FROM `timeRecords`
WHERE
  `date` = :dateToday
  AND `employeeID` = :employeeID
/* Selecting only one employeeID you don't actually need the GROUP BY */
GROUP BY `employeeID`
```

However, this won't report the total time worked if an employee clocks in and out several times during one day. In that case, you would need to `SUM()` the result of the `TIMEDIFF()` for each of the in/out pairs.

Something like:

```
SELECT
  `employeeID`,
  /* Assumes no times overlap across rows */
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`timeOut`, `timeIn`)))) AS `totalTime`
FROM `timeRecords`
WHERE
  `date` = :dateToday
  AND `employeeID` = :employeeID
GROUP BY `employeeID`
```

Comment: When I did the `SUM()` method suggested it gave me a float value I assume it returns the value back in seconds?

Comment: @Yamaha32088 Try the change above, which converts time difference to seconds before summing them up, then converts that sum back to time string (you could also omit the SEC_TO_TIME() and leave it as seconds if you want to process it in PHP)